# How can I apply my dictionary to my developed softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have developed my softkeyboard for support another language.
And I also enabled text prediction on it but it doesn't return any predicted word while typing.
So I have created my .xml dictionary and already convert it to be .dict file

So, question is, how can I apply this dictionary to work with my softkeyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an edit box and you need to search the dictionary for suggestions. 
This is well explained in these two articles

- [Using search dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)
- [Adding custom suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)

You will need to create a ContentProvider. You can use [this application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my late reply. I have see your refer links but I have some question. So, I must provide this feature by myself right? I'm not sure that AnySoftKeyboard already has this feature and I'm still searching for usage.

Comment: You obviously have to code this feature yourself using help from these tutorials given by Google.